# how to override ng2 pdf viewer css

Tags: css, angular

I am rendering pdf in a angular material dialog. I am using [ng2-pdf-viewer](https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer) when I inspect, I see container width is very small which I want to increase.
So, I want to change

[image]

```
.ng2-pdf-viewer-container[_ngcontent-c13] {
     overflow-x: auto; 
}
```

to

```
 .ng2-pdf-viewer-container[_ngcontent-c13] {
         width: 100%;
    }
```

I tried !important but it is not working

How to do that?

Comment: Can you add runnable code snippet of your problem? like Fiddler, codepen etc

Answer (score 13):

this worked for me

```
:host ::ng-deep .ng2-pdf-viewer-container {
width: 100% !important;
```

}

Comment: for my app I needed to add in `overflow-x: initial !important;` 
But that was the selector I needed, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the hint with :host ::ng-deep. In my case I needed :host ::ng-deep .pdfViewer. It depends, you have to look for the nested classes in the dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

```
:host ::ng-deep .ng2-pdf-viewer-container .page {margin-bottom: 0px !important;}
```

this works for me. I want to change the margin-bottom.

Comment: :host ::ng-deep .ng2-pdf-viewer-container .page {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important; 
  }

Comment: I tried this and it changed all the pdf viewer containers to the same size. Is there a way to change individually. I have 3 components in Angular and I need 3 different sizes. I tried a class and I tried in-line style but it is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score -2):

I have used jQuery for this purpose and it worked like charm.

```
$(".ng2-pdf-viewer-container[_ngcontent-c6]").css("overflow-x", "unset");
```

This statement I have written inside the function `afterLoadComplete`.

```
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)"></pdf-viewer>
```

After that you can add your custom CSS properties using jQuery in same function.

Comment: [_ngcontent-c6] should not be used on CSS queries. It's a dynamically generated property by Angular, so it can change if you add/remove components on the DOM.